# Allowing to upload DOCUMENT, EXCEL files in TYPO3 in FAL in the backend

Tags: typo3, typo3-extensions, fal

Is there a way we can allow doc and excel files in the FAL upload in the backend? for e.g we have this in the TCA

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Resource\File::FILETYPE_AUDIO => [
    'showitem' => '
    --palette--;LLL:EXT:lang/locallang_tca.xlf:sys_file_reference.imageoverlayPalette;imageoverlayPalette,
    --palette--;;filePalette',
],
```

but there is not `FILETYPE_DOCUMENT` or something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowed file-types for upload are usually adjusted in Installtool, at `[BE][fileDenyPattern]`.
In Version 8.7 the default entry is `\.(php[3-7]?|phpsh|phtml|pht)(\..*)?$|^\.htaccess$` to avoid access on php-files and on `.htaccess`.

For TCA-settings have a look here: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/Input.html#linkpopup
There is mentioned that usually there are no restrictions configured.